# Waiting for an external application to launch Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web, rtsp

First off: this only needs to work on Macs.

I have a `<meta http-equiv=Refresh Content=1;url=rtsp://example.com/file.sdp` which should automatically ask/open QuickTime player.  I'm trying to make it so a javascript function is executed as soon as QuickTime player launches.

Couldn't it just wait 5 seconds or something?

No: In safari this would be fine; in chrome and firefox i want it to wait until the launch application or ok buttons are pressed before the javascript function is executed

Thanks

Comment: You'd be safer just requiring another user click after qt has launched. What you want is just not possible.

Comment: @bfavaretto So then your saying that the only possible way to do what I want is to have it make a dialog that shows up under the launch application prompt?

Comment: *After* the prompt, actually. The browser has no control of external applications, so you have to rely on the user to tell you QuickTime has launched.

Comment: What I was hoping is that there is a way for you to see what the user clicked in the dialog box that it generates...So: if the dialog box appears; wait until the user clicks an option if option=launch application; do () else do ()

Comment: As far as I know, that's just not possible.

Comment: Ok, well thanks for trying anyway

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the what to trigger in javascript timeout

```
setTimeout ( expression, timeout );
```

Example:

```
function hello() {  
   alert('hello'); // or play anything.
}
setTimeout(hello, 5000);   // unit in miliseconds (5000 means 5 seconds)
```

Comment: As i said before: This would work in safari, but not in chrome/firefox due to the prompt for `launch application`  I need the code to only execute after the QuickTime player begins to launch...well, I'm not sure what else you could wait for that safari then wouldn't throw an error for...anything else you guys can come up with will do though

Comment: ah i see, do u mean the yellow bar at the top that prompts u? i think its a browser privacy preferences and you could not force the browser to do that. what if you find a workaround. to run the function first. *then* play the content?

Comment: theres documentation here [Apple link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/quicktime/Conceptual/QTScripting_JavaScript/bQTScripting_JavaScri_Document/QuickTimeandJavaScri.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001526-CH001-SW3) that allows callback from QuickTime player. but it's pointing to broken source file. the AC_QuickTime.js..

Comment: well: I'm not sure what your talking about with the yelllow bar at the top that prompts u, the thing i'm talking about is a popup in Chrome and Firefox that appears when an external application (such as quicktime, or appstore, or others) are asked to be opened.  Safari just goes ahead and opens the application without any prompt.

Comment: Ah i got it, my bad. I think its the link handler [Google Support Page](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1382847). I still think you cannot remove the prompt as it's a safety feature.

Comment: I don't want to remove the promt; I just want to check what they entered in the prompt; or have it just do javascript when the prompt is exited

Comment: im sorry for being careless in explaining. basically when the prompt comes u have no control as its given to the browser to handle. it is not like javascript confirm(). i would suggest you check the Apple Quicktime callback to read if the user actually play the video.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for the answers.  I'm gonna show what I ended up doing here.

```
<meta http-equiv=Refresh Content=1;url=rtsp://####.com/####.sdp />

<script type='text/javascript'>
function checkfinish() {
var answer = confirm('Finished with this page?')
if (answer)
  window.location = "previous-page"
}
setTimeout ( checkfinish, 5000 )
</script>
```

I figured out what I'm doing wrong:

```
Trying to do this!
```

I decided instead of having it automatically redirect; have it leave a button for return to previous page at the bottom.

Thanks for all the help anyways.